# Only Retrieve Changed Data After ValueEventListener Initiated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to only retrieve only the children that were added / changed after the value event listener was established? From my experience, it seems to fetch every child.

For instance, in a chat based application, if I wanted to fetch the last 10 messages using query as an initialisation step

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Query queryRef = database.getReference(MESSAGES)
        .limitToLast(messagesToLoad);

queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        // Load then new chat message
        ChatMessage message = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
        if (message != null)
        {
            mMessageList.add(0, message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

After that, I want to attach a `ValueEvenListener` that listens to the changes.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(MESSAGES);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ChatMessage message = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
        if (message != null) {
            mMessageList.add(0, message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

EDIT: I've converted to a `childEventListener` for when new messages are added but I obviously can't do that with the single `ValueEventListener` query. I also adjusted it so they are now using the same database reference (`childEventListener` is only called on creation of fragment) but this doesn't seem to change much.

This is just to avoid fetching a whole heap of data for no reason.

Comment: did you end up solving this issue? I am having a similar issue as yours and not sure what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is different than how Firebase works. When we are talking about Firebase, everything is about `listeners`. Because Firebase is a real-time database, every change that is made in your database is provided in real-time. You'll be noticed for changes as long as your listener is active. You can stop listening only if you remove the listener in your `onDestroy()` method like this:

```
yourRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

If you want to know which are the new messages is not necessary to remove the listener. You can add another field to your message named, let say `read` and set it `false` if the message wasn't read and `true` if it was read.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [child event listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener)

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment but after testing properly, this doesn't appear to work. It still loads all the children.